# Revoke connect permission from Public role

Tags: sql-server-2008, permissions, roles

I am using MSSQL 2008 R2. I have a particular database that when it is restored it is being accessible from everyone from the SQL Management Studio. By using the below SQL statement I have identified that the **Public** server role has been granted the connect permission on this database.

```
use db_mydb
SELECT * 
  FROM sys.database_permissions 
 WHERE grantee_principal_id = (SELECT principal_id 
                                 FROM sys.server_principals 
                                WHERE name ='public')
```

With the result of this query being the below

`0  DATABASE    0   0   2   1   CO      CONNECT G   GRANT`

Is there any work around to revoke this permission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution for this was to create an empty database. Then script the tables, views and stored procuders using the **Generate Scripts**. And then import the data using the **Import Data** option. All of this can be done using only the Micosoft SQL Management Studio.

Comment: That means that some login *was set up* on both servers and and the user existed too. So on restore, security was granted automatically. Nothing to do with public, as I mentioned. You can find out which using the sid columns in the 2 sys.xxx_principals views

Comment: The database didn't have any users

Answer (score 0):

One of the correct ways would be

- Run DROP USER all users in the database
- Run DENY CONNECT TO those users

Don't mess with public

Your code is misleading you too:

- The server level public role is unrelated to the database level public role
- `sys.database_permissions.grantee_principal_id` refers to `sys.database_principals`
- For roles, there is no common column between `sys.database_permissions`/`sys.database_principals` and `sys.server_principals`

Comment: Thanks for your post, My issue is that the this particular database doesn't have any user accessed to it and yet is can be accessed. Thus I cannot do something like 

`use db_test; deny connect to TestUser;`

Indeed I did got misleaded by my code. Think the could should have looked more like 
`use db_test; select * from sys.database_permissions where grantee_principal_id = 
(SELECT principal_id from sys.database_principals where name ='public');`

Comment: I'm not trying to mess with the public role. Never-the-less it seems that it was already modified before being migrated from SQL 2000 to SQL 2008 and I am trying to do here is to restore the "default" permissions.

Comment: There is no "default" permission. The users connecting must be sysadmin or they have access already (eg the group/login is on old and new servers)

Comment: All users that can access this database only have the 'Public' server role accessed to them. These users cannot access other databases apart from the one that I am mentioning. The users have been created manually and not migrated from the other server and are normal SQL Authentication users. When the user is scripted it will look like the `CREATE LOGIN [MyTestUser] WITH PASSWORD=N'*****' MUST_CHANGE, DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], CHECK_EXPIRATION=ON, CHECK_POLICY=ON`

Comment: In which case, check sys.server_permissions for some odd permissions.